# Scilab: draw a function of 2 variables in 3D

Tags: scilab

Please, I tried many ways to plot the function `f(x,y)=(x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)` in 3D in Scilab but I couldn't.
My current code:

```
clearglobal
funcprot(0)
function z=f(x,y)
    f(x,y)=(x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)
    x=-10:10
    y=-10:10
    disp([(x,y),z])
endfunction
plot3d(z)
```

Current error:

```
plot3d: Wrong size for input argument #1.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two big mistakes in your code.

#### Your function definition is wrong.

The syntax for defining functions is:

```
function    output = function_name(arguments)
    //computations go here
    output = ...(something)...
endfuncfion
```

Then you could call it like this: `var_A = function_name(2)`, and `var_A` would then store the output of `function_name()` when the argument is 2.

Your function would be correctly defined like this:

```
function z = f(x,y)
    z = (x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)
endfunction
```

You shouldn't redefine `x` and `y` inside `f()` like you did in `x=-10:10` and `y=-10:10` inside `f()`. You actually can do it, but I suppose this not what you want.

#### You have to give actual values to `plot3d()`

When you name the output of `f()` as `z`, it doesn't mean that you already have `z` values. It also doesn't mean that a variable called `z` already existis. They way your code is, you're calling `plot3d()` using an unexisting variable as its argument.

The name of the output doesn't matter once you run the code. Remember example of `var_A` I gave above: you need to write a code that runs the function and creates a variable named `z` that stores the values you want.

Perhaps you thought that if you assign values for `x` and `y` inside the implementation of `f()` , the `z` values would be calculated automatically, but that's not how programming languages usually work.

---

Now, after correcting your `f()`, you can make a real surface plot:

1. Define values for `x` and `y`. The should be vectors (column or line matrices).
2. Use a loop to run `f()` for every possible pair (x,y). The result of this loop will be a `m`-by-`n` matrix, where `m` is the length of `x` and `n`, the length of `y`;
3. Call `plot3d(x,y,z)`. Notice you have do pass `x` and `y` too, not just `z`.

This full code should probably work:

```
function z=f(x,y)
    z=(x*y)/(x^2 + y^2);
endfunction

x = -10:10;
y = -10:10;

for i = 1 : length(x)
    for j = 1 : length(y)
        z(i,j) = f(x(i), y(j)); 
    end
end

plot3d(x,y,z);
```

And the graphic output is:

[image: 1]